# Jquery not able to get elements html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to fetch the HTML of all the span tags, but I am only able to get the inner HTML. This is my code:

```
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
for(var i=0;i<spans.length;i++) {
    alert($(spans[i]).html());
}
```

This only prints the text within the tags, not with the tags. How can I print it with tags?

Comment: Can you please provide codepen or jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var spans = $( "span" );
 spans.each(function(index,element){  
    alert(element.outerHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Hallo</span>
```

You can use outerHTML and jQuery. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Use [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML):

```
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
  alert(spans[i].outerHTML);
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/agb6ja5g/)

Answer (score 0):

theres two ways to grab all span elements on your page.

Native Javascript

```
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
for (var i in spans){
    //print out the whole tag
    console.log(spans[0].outerHTML);
}
```

jQuery

```
var spans = $('span');
spans.each(function(index,elem){ 
    //print out the whole tag
    console.log(elem.outerHTML);
});
```

instead of using alert which is annoying, use console.log(spans); and open your web browsers console to see what was printed out.

Edit: first poster is  right, outerHTML is the way to go.

Comment: But i doesnt make any difference

Comment: The OP mentioned getting the html of ALL of the span tags and keeping the tags attached. I assume that's what this code is about, else I am lost.

Answer (score 0):

```
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

         for(var i=0;i<spans.length;i++){


             alert(        +'<span> '+ $(spans[i]).html())+' </span>';
         }
     }
```

Just added some hard-coded 'bookends' titled 'span'. You can modify them as you wish.
They act as a wrapper for your html and run on each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it:

```js
    var spans = $('span');
    spans.each(function(index,element){  
        alert( $('<div/>').html(element).html() );
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Hallo</span>
```